# How to add service to a WCF Service library. Is this correct?

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF and .Net application. So pardon me if I am asking some basic and silly question.

Basically my project is to create a WCF Service that would call an Oracle Stored Procedure that returns a set of parameters which is then passed to the Exchange Server to send Email.

For this so far I have done something like this:
In VS 2010 Create Project; Visual C#; WCF; select WCF Service Library. 
Described as "A project for creating a WCF service class library (.dll)". 
Gives an app.config 
Debug brings up a WCF Service Host and a WCF Test Client automatically.
I initially followed the MSDN sample that is given below in the following website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731835.aspx

Now I Added another project to the same solution and chose WCF Service Application to host the above in IIS host. This gives me web.config file.

Before I proceed to my next question please let me know if the last step is correct or wrong? 
        To proceed further I tried to add my implementation service reference in web.config file.

When I try to debug I am getting a Service host that is running seperately (an icon on my machine) and a WCF Test Client opens up as well. Is this correct? Now how do I proceed further? I have no clue..
Now do I create methods that would call the Stored Procedure using Data access?

How do I proceed further? I am stuck. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right path you just need to call your stored procedue and then call read the data and invoke method and pass it to client.
Here is full example with screenshot for your help

**SQL Server**
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/468354/WCF-example-for-inserting-and-displaying-data-from

**WCF Data Services and OData for Oracle Database**
http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkWCF/WCFEntityFramework.htm

**Invoking Operations on the Oracle Database WCF**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788075%28v=bts.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I am in the right direction. Is there any example that shows with Oracle Database instead of SQL Server? I am new to this and so would need help in doing with Oracle DB instead of MS SQL.

Comment: I have edited answer you can find you asnwers on link.Good luck but basic concept is same only the diffrence is in data access you will be using Oracle data access rather that SQL Server

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But now stuck in the config file as it is giving error. Will post another question to find out what am I doing wrong. Thanks for this.